# How i can fetch array in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do I fetch the values of my dictionary not a loop. I know how to get a single value using:

```
NSString *valueStr = [dict objectForKey:@"Key2"];
```

I need to fetch by looping all keys, I need to search a value in the dictionary.

Comment: Please be more clear what you are trying to achieve. By array do you mean dictionary? What are you trying to fetch?

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you are trying to use a [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you would want to do something like this:

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]){
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

or if you dont want to use looping you can the following:

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSString *key in <#dictionary#>)
{
    <#!loopcontents#>
    [dictionary objectForKey:key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have a `NSDictionary`, you can access all keys/values with:

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
```

refering https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

of course you can loop over that key-value pairs with

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {

    //get value
    NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:key];

    //print to log
    NSLog (@"%@, %@", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers from Omarj and Rene:

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{
    NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: thank you, i had the same idea and edited my post while you answered :)