# How i can get key by the value?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can fetch array in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397780/how-i-can-fetch-array-in-xcode)

How can I get key by the value?

Now I am fetching value by the key, like this:

```
NSString *valueStr = [dict objectForKey:@"Key2"];
```

I need to get key by value.

Comment: Why would you ever need this, the only way I could see how to do this is loop thru all the properties and check the value. But in my opinion it just bad design and should never ever be needed.

Comment: You should change your question "How i can get keys by the value?"

Answer (score 4):

```
for (NSString* key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
   NSString* value = [dictionary objectForKey:key]
   if(value equalsToString:@"SearchedValue") {
      searchedValue = value;
      keyForSearchedValue = key;
}
```

But this is not the recommended way how to code. instead you should search by key, not by value.
And please do not create 3 new question for the same topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *valueStr = ...;
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeysForObject:valueStr];
```

returns an array containing all keys which have the given value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

That's an expensive operation as `NSDictionary` (like any *map* collection class) is designed to hold values by key.

You can do it like this, however (assuming both key and value are `NSString`):

```
NSString *wantValue = @"tulips";
for (NSString *name in dict)
{
    NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:name];
    if ([value isEqualToString:wantValue])
    {
        NSLog(@"name '%@' matches", name);
    }
}
```